# How do I convert a List<object> to a Newtonsoft JObject in my C# Controller?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My colleagues and I are new to ReactJS. We are trying to return a list of users from a controller action as a JObject, and are encountering the following error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

Each User in the list is a complex object. Here is the controller code (.NET C#).

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllUsers")]
public JObject GetAllUsers()
{
    List<User> UserList = UserData.GetAllUsers();
    return (JObject)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserList);
}
```

If there is a better way to return a list to ReactJS, we can explore that as well. We were unable to locate any examples with a JObject returning a list of complex objects. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't change the signature of your method to `public JsonResult GetAllUsers()` and then `return new JsonResult(UserList)`?

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: If your endpoint is supposed to return an object, you can't return a list.

Comment: Glad it worked!